# Stacked Bar Graph with Multiple Columns of Integers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stackedbarseries

Looking for some help with what I am assuming is a very simple task.  From my data below, I want to create a stacked bar graph, with the `fill = colnames(df_Consumers)[2,4]`.  I'm trying to get the x-axis to be `df_Consumers$Month`, the y-axis as `df_Consumers$Referrals` with the 2nd and 4th columns being the stacked bar graphs.  I hope this makes sense.  Apologies in advance if I am too vague.  My ggplot code and data are below.  Thanks in advance!

```
ggplot(df_Consumers, aes(x = Month, y = Referrals)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = df_Consumers[2, 4]))
```

[image]

Comment: You should not add data as images. We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for this.  I couldn't figure out how to add the data to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` likes long data frames. I'd suggest the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_Consumers %>%
  select(-Referrals) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(New.Consumers, No.Fill), names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Month, y = value, fill = type) + 
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have been trying to do for hours.  I do have one question though.  The graph is displaying across the x-axis in a random order.  How can I change it so Sep 2020 is first and so on?  Also, for myself and others, can you briefly explain the long data frame for ggplot.  This is the first I've heard of this.   I'm also researching it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just a quick update for others that might have the same question as me.  Below is a link about long vs wide data frames and how to convert them.  http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: Whenever you'd like to order anything in `ggplot2`, convert the column to an ordered factor. Here, I would add `mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = c("Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Nov 2020", "Dec 2020", "Jan 2021", "TOTALS")) %>%` after the `pivot_longer` line. That should get your x-axis in order.

Comment: Had to play with it a bit.  For some reason it wasn't working, but I figured it out from your suggestion using ```mutate```.  Thank you again!